# Get value of list by name attribute in R

Tags: r

```
contrast=list("1"="profit")
input=readline("please input")
please input1
input
[1] "1"
class(input)
[1] "character"
contrast[[input]]
[1] "profit"
contrast$"1"
[1] "profit"
contrast$input
NULL
```

Why  `contrast$input`  is not equal to  `contrast$"1"`?
the value of input is "1",the class is character too.

```
eval(input)
[1] "1"
contrast$(eval(input))
Error: unexpected '(' in "contrast$("
contrast$eval(input)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
eval(paste(input))
[1] "1"
class(eval(paste(input)))
[1] "character"
contrast$eval(paste(input))
Error: attempt to apply non-function
contrast$(eval(paste(input)))
Error: unexpected '(' in "contrast$("
```

Is there no way to get the value via  contrast$input?

Comment: From the documentation: "Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]"

Comment: you mean i can never get value via  contrast$input?

Comment: @FfYy Like joran mentions - you just can't do it.  But why would you want to do that when the perfectly good alternative `contrast[[input]]` is available?

Comment: @joran, post your first comment as an answer ... ?  (I'm sure there are duplicates or very-near-duplicates out there, but can't be bothered to look for them right now ...) StackOverflow doesn't like it if I try to search for `[r] "[[" "$"`

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible. From the documentation (`?Extract`):

> "Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main
>   difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does.
>   x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]"

In general, `$` is intended for interactive use, but for programming (scripts, functions, etc.) you should use `[[`.